# Getting null meta in early transactions

Tags: metadata, transaction, historical-data

I'm using GetTransaction API on bigtable nodes to retrieve transaction 54CkqBDn3VV657fEzGPekEfxEve1X6hWSWfqjdF3J3DhsK9Arm8M34RHGYu1dppKS35goRv1X4BL75ttfx4SbeLC. Then I noticed that meta field is null in the response.

I found it's very common for transactions in early epochs(<= epoch 6). Also I cannot find meta on most indexers(Solana explorer/Solana.FM/Solana scanner). What is the reason behind this?

Answer (score 2):

Very simply, the meta didn't exist at that time, so there was none to upload!

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to fetch the meta of early transactions, you can use a Promise which would retry until the transaction's commitment reaches `MAX` confirmations. I would recommend using the [`p-retry`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/p-retry) library by Sindre Sorhus, which makes it easier to work with Promise retrying.

```
const transactionMetadata = await pRetry(
  async () => {
    const connection = new Connection(rpcUrls.get(session.network)!);
    const fetchedTransactionMetadata = await connection.getTransaction(
      signature
    );
    return fetchedTransactionMetadata !== null
      ? fetchedTransactionMetadata
      : Promise.reject(new Error("Transaction isn't confirmed yet"));
  },
  {
    retries: 5,
  }
);
```